# Large array of object causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, linux, memory, g++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run this code under Ubuntu 12.10 using G++.

```
NodeFeature *feature_all;    
NODE_NO = 20449;    
feature_all = new NodeFeature[NODE_NO];
```

I get the message `Segmentation Fault`. `NodeFeature` is a struct:

```
struct NodeFeature
    {
        int len; //length of vector
        double *val; //vector of observational features
        int *index; //vetor of indexes of features
        int *label_start; //array indexes of the starting point for each label
        int *label; //the labels being activated at this node
    };
```

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

EDIT:
In case you need to see the whole code and the data to test it, both are avaible here: http://vietlabs.com/crf-sl/

Comment: Where did the segfault happened ? It's hard to guess anything from the code you posted (apart from "using one of the struct's pointers incorrectly).

Comment: It seems that the segment fault is not caused by the codes you posted here. More information is required.

Comment: I have debugged the code line by line, at this line of the code it happens. What other info you need?

Comment: @MOLi Do you mean the segfault happen on `feature_all = new NodeFeature[NODE_NO];`? How is `feature_all` declared ?

Comment: NodeFeature *feature_all;

Comment: @JBL yes, it happens at that line.

Comment: Possibly an XY problem, you should post whole code.

Comment: Ugh, why all these pointers?!

Comment: You can download the whole code and the needed data for testing it here: http://vietlabs.com/crf-sl/

Comment: Certainly the crash is not becuse the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

What type is `feature_all` declared as?
It should be:

```
NodeFeature *feature_all;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to allocate around **`4 GB`** of data dynamically. 
I would expect it would crash, for more information see this link.[The limited allocation size C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455658/the-limited-allocation-size-c)

It is happening because the member `SeqFeature::OB_F_MAX` is un-initialized(which turns out to be a negative value) and this value is assigned to `SeqClassifier::OB_F_SIZE`, which is used for computation in the function `SeqClassifier::initParam` where it gets converted into a huge positive value and this is given as the size for creating the `double` array dynamically.

In simple, the uninitialized value of `OB_F_MAX` is causing the `size` of the array to have a huge positive value. 
This ,**huge** positive value which is passed on to `new` operator which causes the size to be around 4 GB.

Also, note that on 32-bit x86 systems you can't request for `4 GB` or even `3 GB` of memory as pointed out by the link mentioned above.

Comment: You are saying that the code takes a lot of space and nothing can be done for running it?
Could you run it on your machine?

Comment: There shold be a way, but I don't know how to achieve this. Yes I have runned it in VS2010 and I got the crash at the above mentioned function.

Comment: Intialize that variable and if the size of the memory requested my your program is within bounds it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am running it under Ubuntu. I tried another piece of code but still have the same problem. Instead of newing that array kf struct I wrote this: int* temp = new int[2*NODE_NO]; It still says 'Segmentation fault'. i guess that's the problem with the number of elements. So how others deal with huge number of data?

Comment: Maybe try searching on google, or just ask another question here. I don't know how to get away with this problem.