# Invalid allocation size: 4294967295 byte

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, graph

I was coding about ullman algorithm and when I run my program I faced with :
"Invalid allocation size: 4294967295 byte" error.  it could be about vector? or anything else? could any help me about this?

```
void ullman(Graph &graph,Pattern pattern,int **p,int k)
{
bool flg=true;
if(k>=pattern.vertexNum)
{
    int **tmp;
    tmp=new int *[pattern.vertexNum];
    for(int i=0;i<pattern.vertexNum;i++)
        tmp[i]=new int [graph.vertexNum];

    for(int i=0;i<pattern.vertexNum;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<graph.vertexNum;j++)
            tmp[i][j]=p[i][j];
    graph.permutation.push_back(tmp);

    return;
}
for(int i=0;i<graph.vertexNum;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<pattern.vertexNum;j++)
        if(p[j][i])
            flg=false;
    if(!flg)
    {
        flg=true;
        continue;
    }
    p[k][i]=1;
    if(examin(graph,pattern,p,k))
        ullman(graph,pattern,p,k+1);
    p[k][i]=0;
}

return;}

bool examin(Graph &graph,Pattern pattern,int **p,int k)
 {
bool flg=true;
int **pt;  
pt=new int *[graph.vertexNum];
for(int i=0;i<graph.vertexNum;i++)
    pt[i]=new int [pattern.vertexNum];
for(int i=0;i<pattern.vertexNum;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<graph.vertexNum;j++)
        pt[j][i]=p[i][j];

char **tmp; // P*graph
char **tmp2; // tmp*pt

tmp= new char *[pattern.vertexNum];
for(int i=0;i<pattern.vertexNum;i++)
    tmp[i]=new char[graph.vertexNum];
for(int i=0;i<pattern.vertexNum;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<graph.vertexNum;j++)
        tmp[i][j]='-';

tmp2=new char *[pattern.vertexNum];
for(int i=0;i<pattern.vertexNum;i++)
    tmp2[i]=new char[pattern.vertexNum];
for(int i=0;i<pattern.vertexNum;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<pattern.vertexNum;j++)
        tmp2[i][j]='-';

for(int j=0;j<pattern.vertexNum;j++)
    for(int i=0;i<graph.vertexNum;i++)
        if(p[j][i])
            for(int m=0;m<graph.vertexNum;m++)
                tmp[j][m]=graph.G[i][m];

for(int m=0;m<pattern.vertexNum;m++)
    for(int i=0;i<graph.vertexNum;i++)
        if(pt[i][m])
            for(int j=0;j<pattern.vertexNum;j++)
                tmp2[j][m]=tmp[j][i];

for(int i=0;i<pattern.vertexNum;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<pattern.vertexNum;j++)
        if(pattern.P[i][j]!='-' && tmp2[i][j]!='-')
            if(pattern.P[i][j] != tmp2[i][j])
            {
                flg=false;
                break;
            }
    if(!flg)
        break;
}
if(flg)
    return true;
else
    return false;}
```

Comment: Let me guess, 32-bit OS?

Comment: Check out this link .. 
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470003/why-am-i-getting-invalid-allocation-size-4294967295-bytes-instead-of-an-std"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are passing `-1` for the size, because `4294967295` corresponds to `0xFFFFFFFF`, i.e. the negative one in two's complement representation.

Since the only value that you pass to `new [...]` is `vertexNum`, that's the value that you need to check. Add a condition at the top of your functions to see if `graph.vertexNum` or `pattern.vertexNum` is negative, set a breakpoint inside the conditional, and see what part of your code is making the invalid call:

```
void ullman(Graph &graph,Pattern pattern,int **p,int k) {
    if(pattern.vertexNum < 0) {
        cerr << "pattern.vertexNum is negative" << endl; // Set brekpoint here
    }
    bool flg=true;
    ... // The rest of your code
}
```